# Sqoop: converting string to date when exporting data from HDFS to Teradata

Tags: java, hadoop, teradata, etl, sqoop

I have a table in teradata and one column, `update_date`, is defined as DATE. Format is YYYYMMDD. I need to upload files in HDFS to the table. The files are comma separated text files. The column that corresponds to `update_date` is a string of format 'YYYYMMDD'.

When I tried to export the data using command:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:teradata://tdwc/DATABASE=sandbox --username xxxx --password yyyy --table mytable --export-dir hftp://gdoop-namenode/path/to/myfiles/
```

The command failed with error

```
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)  
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '20160129'
```

How can I resolve this without changing the schema of the table?

Comment: Can you use --map-column-java id={column}, value=Date as an option on your sqoop command line? That will depend on whether java will interpret your YYYYMMDD formatted string as a valid date.